# Java Stream groupingBy retain original collection as well

Tags: java, java-stream

When using java stream api, is there a way to use Collectors.groupingBy and add the original Collection as well?
So when I use something like this code:

```
interface SomeObject {
    public String getA();
    public String getB();
}

Collection<SomeObject> obj;
Map<String,List<SomeObject>> grouped = obj.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(SomeObject::getA, "ALL A"));
```

I could specify a String value where the whole original Collection is put into the Map as well.
This would ofc be easy enough to do afterwards if I use only one groupingBy:

```
grouped.put("ALL A",obj.stream().collect(toList()));
```

but for several chained ones:

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<SomeObject>>> chaingrouped = obj.stream()
         .collect(groupingBy(SomeObject::getA, "ALL A",       
                       groupingBy(SomeObject::getB, "ALL B")));
```

this would be very helpful for later usage when I need to have all possible partitions of the original Collection:

```
chaingrouped.entrySet().forEach(entryA -> {
    entryA.entrySet().forEach(entryB -> {
        // this now has the original Collection in full
        // partitioned by getB additionally to the standard groupingBy
        // which would only have the getA partitioned again partitioned by getB 
    });
});
```

For a countries/cities/districts example:
I'd like to have the Collection of countries grouped by cities and then grouped by districts and later run some statistics on each grouped supset.
So for example I could look at the number of streets in each district.
But I would also like to have an 'ALL' country to select from, just partitioned by cities and districts. Or select a specific country, use the 'ANY CITY' and have this subset partitioned by districts again. etc.

[edit for clarification]

Comment: I don't understand your question. groupingBy is used separate the elements of a collection in several groups. If every group contains the whole collection, what's the point? Could you give a concrete example, let's say with cities and countries, of what you want to do?

Comment: Can you replace `[ALLATTRIBUTE]` with something meaningful, e.g. something adhering to the syntax of the Java programming language and having a recognizable relationship to the rest of your code?

Comment: i hope the edit made it more clear what i want to do

Comment: It isn't possible. Also I don't think that such usage of stream api is a good code style

Comment: i've been using the stream api for this because of the convenience of `parallelStream()` - which helps with the quite huge Collection

Comment: `groupingby` puts each element in _exactly_ one group, not more. If you want that, your separate call to `grouped.put` is the way to go, but instead I would just pass a reference to the original collection along instead of putting that stuff into the `grouped` map where it does not belong.